Property 'lastSeenAt' does not exist on type 'ChatHeaderProps'
I feel like this error makes no sense because I already access field by FeedTypes key. But it still complaining about properties does not exist.
One thing I can do is a strict equal like props.type === FeedTypes.CONVERSATION but as I mentioned before it really doesn't make sense because I already access field by props.type:
export type ChatHeaderProps =
| {
      name: string;
      isVerified?: boolean;
      type: FeedTypes.CONVERSATION;
      lastSeenAt: string;
  }
| {
      name: string;
      isVerified?: boolean;
      type: FeedTypes.GROUP;
      members: number;
  };

const ChatHeader = (props: ChatHeaderProps) => {
    // another code here...

    const titles: Record<Exclude<FeedTypes, 'user'>, string> = {
        conversation: `last seen ${getRelativeTimeString(new Date(props.lastSeenAt), 'en-US')}`,
        group: `${props.members} members`,
    }

    return (
       // another jsx here
      <Typography as='p' variant='secondary'>
        {titles[props.type]}
      </Typography>            
    );
};

export default ChatHeader;

Here is error:
Property 'lastSeenAt' does not exist on type 'ChatHeaderProps'.
  Property 'lastSeenAt' does not exist on type '{ name: string; isVerified?: boolean | undefined; type: FeedTypes.GROUP; members: number; }'.

Property 'members' does not exist on type 'ChatHeaderProps'.
  Property 'members' does not exist on type '{ name: string; isVerified?: boolean | undefined; type: FeedTypes.CONVERSATION; lastSeenAt: string; }'.


Defining props as one object | another object seems like an antipattern. Wouldn't it make more sense to just make members and lastSeenAt optional in the type

It also seems like you could just lift some of the logic up (it's already kind of there anyway, you're passing in all the data and the type to switch on) and pass in a single prop for title.

yep that's sounds way better, sometimes i just overthinking
